# Javascript - data accessing

Tags: javascript, database

I'm trying to access and display the data stored in a particular url. But my code wasn't running correctly. Any suggestion for this?

```
function getData( theURL ) {
   var xmlHttp = null;
   xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xmlHttp.open( "GET", theURL, false );
   xmlHttp.send( null );
   return xmlHttp.responseText;
}
var url = "https://cloudant.com/futon/document.html?acharya%2Ftoxtweet/ff558f75077e8c758523cd3bd8ffdf88";
getData(url);
```

Comment: What does "wasn't running correctly" mean?

Comment: Are you sure you are not violating xmlhttprequest same origin policy?

Comment: You can not send ajax request to cross domain, it should be same domain. you have to use iframe technique the same technique also used by facebook.

Comment: can u explain bit more what u actually wnt

Comment: the URL contains info. I wanted to display those info on a page.

Answer (score 3):

XMLHttpRequest only works on the same domain.

If you have a server-side setup, you could proxy the desired page so it arrives from your server.

Answer (score 1):

Since XMLHttpRequest doesn't allow cross domain requests, I believe you can use three solutions. The usability will be depend on the services you are integrating.

1. Use JSONP. If the external URL supports JSONP responses you can use that directly to call cross domains. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP
2. Server Side Proxy (As explained by @Kolink)
3. Server side scripting. Assume you use PHP at your server side. You can call the external URL via PHP then output relevant data to your page within your domain. The way you have to do this is depending on the server side scripting language.

Answer (score 0):

Another and pure-js solution is to utilize YQL, checked:
http://christianheilmann.com/2010/01/10/loading-external-content-with-ajax-using-jquery-and-yql/
(scroll to the bottom for complete script) - works fine.